# Facebook Real-time updated does not call our servers

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

We had integrated facebook real-time updates a while ago and it worked fine.

Recently we have seen that the callbacks are not happening.

we checked our subscriptions and it looks correct.

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 array(4) {
  ["object"]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["callback_url"]=>
  string(62) "https://OUR_CALLBACK_URL"
  ["fields"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "friends"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "likes"
  }
  ["active"]=>
  bool(true)
}
[1]=>
```

But when the user makes a like or changes the likes. we do not get a callback.

Comment: strangely it works for permissions and not for user object.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you solved it?

Comment: It looks like it was some facebook issue. It got resolved by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Facebook does have bugs and it could be a temporary outage too.  I would suggest trying to re-register your subscriptions and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was some facebook issue. It got resolved by itself.